# Upgrading to PHP 5.3 using Plesk or SSH

Tags: php, apache-2.2

How do I go about upgrading from PHP 5.1.6 to 5.3? I just got a virtual server with Plesk on it and am a newbie with linux/apache/plesk.

Comment: What OS is your VPS running on?

Comment: CentOS (I think)

Comment: Try `cat /etc/redhat-release`. If it exists, it'll tell you what version of CentOS you'll have (and if you have it at all :)).

Comment: CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

Comment: did you get this solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so I figured out how to upgrade it !

IN PLESK 10!

task & settings -> panel -> updates and upgrades

then at the top of the page there is a button "Updates source and installation settings" click on that

then very important!

change the menu option "Download installation files from" to "Official Parallels Updates Server"

click save

then click "add components" button

you will the be given a list of of options and you should see PHP5.3 support

then click "continue"

and your done !

easy ; ^ )

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any php install already, you can do

```
yum -y install php53
```

Comment: what does -y do ?

Comment: it automatically answers yes to any questions

Comment: ohh cool i still can't get it upgraded

Answer (score 0):

Via SSH you can just

```
sudo yum update php
```

I believe plesk should just be able to keep up on what php version you are running but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that 5.3 is not the default version for Centos 5.5 - indeed, looking at a nearby [Centos mirror](http://mirrors.manchester.icecolo.com/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/) it uses 5.1.5 but provide 5.3 under a different package name (php53). I suspect that trying to run both packages concurrently will cause problems. So I guess the solution would be to remove the current PHP packages and install the php53 packages - or upgrade the entire OS to Centos 6 (erk!).

Centos is essentially a clone of RedHat Enterprise Linux - which has a parallel open development project called Fedora: if you can't find documentation on package management using yum on Centos, then have a look at the RHEL and Fedora docs.

Don't try to do any of this using Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk  do not ship PHP as it’s integrated part, you have to  upgrade php  outside plesk and plesk won't provide support on it.

Atomic channel create an script to upgrade the php.

You can get the details from the [link.](http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP)

Using atomic channel script you can upgrade the php in plesk

Comment: i get errors when i try their method

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to plesk 10 which includes php 5.3 by default. The latest auto installer also has an option to upgrade php to 5.3. You can find the auto installer at /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller.